# Set of prometheus rules for self managed opensearch cluster health monitoring

Tags: prometheus, alert, monitoring, opensearch

we are moving from aws managed opensearch to self managed.  Aws has a nice list of recommendations for cloudwatch alarms to monitor the health of the cluster.

I am looking for similar for self managed as I know there are more things I need to be worried about that aws was managing, but I don’t know what they are...

We are running in kubernetes and I already have the metrics flowing into prometheus.